# 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-8

I want to manage the authorization in the routes so I create a middleware called "**role**"
This is the role middleware handle function:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $role = Auth::user()->role_id;
    $emp_id = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $clt_id = Auth::user()->client_id;
    if ($role == 3745639763)
    {
        return $next($request);

    } else if ($role == 1 && $emp_id == NULL)
    {
       return redirect('employee/con-reg');

    } else if ($role == 2 && $clt_id == NULL)
    {

        return $next($request);

    } else if ($role == 1 && $emp_id != NULL)
    {

        return redirect('client/con-reg');

    } else if ($role == 2 && $clt_id != NULL)
    {

        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

This is my routes for the employee:

```
Route::group([
'prefix'=> 'employee',
'middleware' => 'role',
'as' => 'employee.'
], function () {
    Route::get('/con-reg', function () {
        $works = Work::all();
        return view('employee/con-register', compact('works'));
    })->name('con-reg');

    Route::post('/store', [EmployeeController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::post('/profile', [EmployeeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
});
```

and This is the home route, after the login or register you will be redirect to the home page, and this is where I also put my middlware because he can access the home after continue his registration with giving us more needed Information for his chosen role:

```
Route::view('/home', 'home')->middleware('role');
```

This is **Kernal.php** file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'emp' => \App\Http\Middleware\emp::class,
    // 'clt' => \App\Http\Middleware\clt::class,
    'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\role::class, //<------This is My Middleware
];
```

so now When I Logged in it didn't redirect me to the **con-register** view, but instead of it the error above appears to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's because route **employee/con-reg** protected with this middleware.
After redirect - you go into the loop check->redirect
You need to disable **role** middleware for route **employee/con-reg**

### Fast solution:

```
if ($request->path() === 'employee/con-reg'){
   return $next($request);
}
```

### Right solution:

Put this action in controller (not in Closure, it's bad practice) and disable middleware for it

Comment: Did you meant " $request->path() " ??

Comment: Where should I add it

Comment: In your middleware as first statement

Comment: but I need the employee to access the "employee/con-reg" only one time